# Native Query in spring boot JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, boot

I'm using spring boot 2.6 and spring boot JPA version 2.6.4.  I was interested in pull last five records from mysql table by using next query
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM produit p ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 5")
public Collection getProduit();
Normally in the @Query block, i need to add the nativeQuery = true after the value property but the nativeQuery attribute is not defined. What am i missing?

Please help, already 5 hours searching on this.

Comment: are you saying that this doesn't work @Query(value="SELECT * FROM produit p ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 5", nativeQuery=true) public Collection getProduit() ?

Comment: Yes. Adding nativeQuery=true fails. nativeQuery indefined for type Query

Answer (score 0):

When using a native query you need to define a mapping of the values to for example your own type. You could use interface based projections when you only need to read data see [interface based projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces). Then your could would look like

```
@Query(nativeQuery=true, value="SELECT * FROM produit p ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 5")
Set<Projection> getProduit();
```

Another thing to check would be what import is used for the @Query annotation, maybe it is the wrong one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I solved the issue after your suggestion. It was a wrong import that was causing the error